# Set entry tab value in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a project using Python 2.7 and Tkinter. I have a window with a lot of tkinter `Entry` boxes and I would like to be able to tab though them in a different order to their creation, which is the current order. Is there a way to give them all a "Tab Value" like in HTML text boxes?

Comment: Some code as example would be good.

Comment: i could not really think of any useful code to give :/

Comment: I _think_ it depends on row number & column number

Comment: @shaktimaan: no, it has nothing to do with rows and columns.